# Show all sections for node util.debuglog

Tags: node.js, debugging

Is there a way to show all sections of Node.js built-in `uitl.debuglog`?

Let's say I want to debuglog between multiple files covering different aspects. For example, such as `controllers`, `services` and more. I would set each's debuglog section respectively. NODE_DEBUG can get grossly long and if I add a new section, then I have to restart nodemon.

I thought something like `NODE_DEBUG=* node app.js` would work but it doesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I'm using [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) now. It allows with `DEBUG=*`